# Parsing JSON in C# issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i have a problem parsing the json, and i hope someone could help.

Here's a JSON response i get from the service

```
{

    "name":"UPDATE_QUEUE",
    "args":[
        {
            "message":[
                {
                    "service_id":1,
                    "entered":"01:00",
                    "arrival":"01:00"
                },
                {
                    "service_id":2,
                    "entered":"01:00",
                    "arrival":"01:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

And here's my Class for the JSON object

```
    class QueueItem
    {
        public RootObject RootObject { get; set; }
    }


    public class Message
    {
        public int service_id { get; set; }
        public string entered { get; set; }
        public string arrival { get; set; }
    }

    public class Arg
    {
        public List<Message> message { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Arg> args { get; set; }
    }
```

And here's my call

```
QueueItem items
 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueItem>(data.MessageText);
```

I am using Newtonsoft JSON for c# .NET

When i try to call `items.RootObject.name` i don't get anything, not even trigger for the event ( for example `messageBox.Show(items.RootObject.name)` ) .

Comment: What is `API.jsonObjects.DispatchQueueItem`? Why don't you deserialize to the correct type `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deserializing to the wrong type. You should call

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API.jsonObjects.RootObject>(data.MessageText);
```

The `RootObject` class matches the JSON which you are deserializing.